# If a java method accepts (Object, Object...), is there a way to feed a single parameter into this?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I have a 3rd party library (Springfox, but it doesn't really matter which one here) with a method with signature `tags(Tag first, Tag... remaining)`. Because I need to feed about a dozen Tags into this method, I'd like to split that off into a separate method for readability and maintainability:

```
public Tag[] generateTags(){
    return new Tag[]{
        new Tag("Tag1", "Tag 1 Description"),
        // other tags
    };
}
```

The problem is that I can't simply feed a Tag[] array into the 3rd party library method, because it doesn't match the method signature for tags(Tag, Tag...). I'm getting the error

> The method tags(Tag, Tag...) in the type Docket is not applicable for the arguments (Tag[])

at compile time. This is of course fully expected, though I find it somewhat weird that the Java compiler doesn't recognize that the varArgs argument is of the same type as the argument before it and allows the array to fill both of them.

Beyond the simple solution of defining the first tag inside the tags() calls and then defining the other tags in the external method, are there any other solutions for this?

Comment: so the problem is you get a compile time error in the line calling the `signature` method?

Comment: explain more your question please... what exactly do you need? from an Array of Objects to a method with params from that array? 
something like that:
 Object[] data = new Object[] {new Object(),new Object()};  --> yourLib.method(data[0],data[1]);   is that what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @AdamSiemion Yeah. I've added the specific error I'm getting. I'm probably not the first person to have this problem with variadic functions in Java, but I was surprised that noone asked this question yet.

Comment: @fitDeveloper Something like that, but intead of data[1] as the second argument, it needs to put the rest of the array there, so everything apart from data[0].

Comment: @Nzal the first argument is not a vararg, so you must call it like `tags(t, a)` where `t` is `Tag` and `a` is an array of `Tag`

Comment: @AdamSiemion yeah, I understand that much from all the tutorials on it, but I was wondering if there isn't some sort of workaround for this that allows me to separate the definition of all the tags in a separate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a wrapper method to solve your issue. Just split the first Tag from your Array and feed the the rest into the second argument:

```
public void tagsWrapper(Tag[] tags){
    Tag first = tags[0];
    Tag[] other = Arrays.copyOfRange(tags, 1, tags.length);
    tags(first, other);
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the core of this answer, which is using array indexes and Arrays.copyOfRange to pass the parameters into the function. The wrapper method doesn't quite work because the tags method is part of a builder pattern, so I can't easily put a wrapper around it.